# Data binding doesn't work in a specific case (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope

Here is my problem : 
When I click on the button after having modified my model "*urlservicerest*", my property "*$scope.urlservicerest*" stays initialized to "hello". 
I tried to update data with $scope.$apply, but no more success. I don't understand why "*$scope.urlservicerest*" is not update, whereas the databinding as already been created.

```
//file.html

<input type="input" ng-model="urlservicerest"></
<button type="button"  ng-click="refresh()"> Rafraichir </button>


//script.js:

var field = $scope.urlservicerest = "hello";

  $scope.refresh = function () {
    alert(field);
}
```

Comment: did you update you `<html>` tag like `<html data-ng-app=''>` ??

Comment: don't expect `field` to hold its value (bound to the scope).  That is what `$scope` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular binds to scoped properties.  So, in your case `$scope.urlservicerest` will be two-way bound when the input value changes.

You are alerting the value of `field`, which is not two-way bound.

Adding a second alert for the scoped property shows that `$scope.urlservicerest` is bound correctly:

```
  $scope.refresh = function () {
    alert(field);
    alert($scope.urlservicerest);
  }
```

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s5fmS2?p=preview) demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

I have update a demo on JS fiddle Hope that will help you

[Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g54Ft/1/)

i think you need to add `<html data-ng-app="">` to your page